# Adjust spacing of delimiters in amsmath Xmatrix environment

Tags: spacing, amsmath, matrices

I am using the `Xmatrix` environment ('X' stands for any of 'p','b','B','v','V') from `amsmath` package. I am able to control the spacing between columns using the `\arraycolsep` parameter (for example, with the instruction `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{10pt}`); the problem is that such parameter does not take care of the spacing between the first column and the left delimiter (and similarly, between the last column and the right delimiter).

> Is there some parameter controlling the spacing between delimiters and the nearest columns?

Comment: No, those environments simply remove the `\arraycolsep` at either side.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Is there some way to adjust this spacing (say, with "phantom" first and last columns?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Xmatrix` environments essentially do

```
\left<delimiter>\env@matrix<contents>\endmatrix\right<delimiter>
```

where the `\left` and `\right` bits are not used for `matrix`, of course.

It is not `\matrix<contents>\endmatrix` for technical reasons due to `\matrix` and `\pmatrix` already being defined in the LaTeX kernel (because they were in plain TeX).

The purpose of `\env@matrix` and `\endmatrix` is to do `\hskip-\arraycolsep` respectively before opening `array` and after closing it.

You can define a generic matrix environment; it also allows for specifying the column alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { genmatrix }
 {
  type .tl_set:N  = \l__genmatrix_type_tl,
  cols .tl_set:N  = \l__genmatrix_cols_tl,
  sep  .dim_set:N = \l__genmatrix_sep_dim,
  side .dim_set:N = \l__genmatrix_side_dim,
  type .initial:n = {},
  side .initial:n = 0pt,
 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{genmatrix}{O{}}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { genmatrix }
   {
    sep = \arraycolsep,
    cols = *{\value{MaxMatrixCols}}{c},
    #1
   }
  \dim_set_eq:NN \arraycolsep \l__genmatrix_sep_dim
  \genmatrix_open:V \l__genmatrix_type_tl
  \skip_horizontal:n { \l__genmatrix_side_dim - \l__genmatrix_sep_dim }
  \cs_set_eq:cc { @ifnextchar } { new@ifnextchar }
  \exp_args:NV \array \l__genmatrix_cols_tl
 }
 {
  \endarray
  \skip_horizontal:n { \l__genmatrix_side_dim - \l__genmatrix_sep_dim }
  \genmatrix_close:V \l__genmatrix_type_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \genmatrix_open:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {p}{ \left( }
    {b}{ \left[ }
    {v}{ \left| }
    {B}{ \left\lbrace }
    {V}{ \left\| }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \genmatrix_close:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {p}{ \right) }
    {b}{ \right] }
    {v}{ \right| }
    {B}{ \right\rbrace }
    {V}{ \right\| }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \genmatrix_open:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \genmatrix_close:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{genmatrix}[type=p]
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 12
\end{genmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{genmatrix}[type=p,side=4pt,sep=10pt]
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 12
\end{genmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{genmatrix}[type=p,side=4pt,sep=10pt,cols=rrr]
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 12
\end{genmatrix}
\\
\begin{genmatrix}[type=b]
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 12
\end{genmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{genmatrix}[type=B,side=4pt,sep=10pt]
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 12
\end{genmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{genmatrix}[type=v,side=4pt,sep=10pt,cols=rrr]
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 12
\end{genmatrix}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you might try adding (just one) example with a negative value in the first column.  especially with the digits aligned ans the minus off to the left.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this case I rather prefer to use `array` environment directly instead.